# Use simplejson with Python 2.7 on GAE

Tags: json, google-app-engine, python-2.7, simplejson

Having trouble using `simplejson` with google app engine running Python 2.7.

Just switched from Python 2.5 on the Master/Slave datastore to Python 2.7 on the High Replication Datastore. This used to work:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
```

Now in order to use json, I can do this:

```
import json
```

However, I have a need to use `simplejson`. This works on the localhost debugger, but not on the server:

```
import simplejson
```

How can I use this library when running Python 2.7 on GAE?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you need `simplejson`? The `json` module in the standard library *is* simplejson.

Comment: `from django.utils import simplejson` works for me with Python 2.7 and HR datastore.

Comment: It might be the Django version as I think this changes when you go to HR datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think json and simplejson are now compatible. If you've got code using simplejson, you could try

```
import json as simplejson
```